# CSS3 Text Hover Effect Moving Background like a Progress bar

Tags: css

I've already tried working on different styles of Text Background Hover effect **BUT NOT THIS ONE.**

The link below is a gif to what I'm talking about.

http://i.imgur.com/Dw01GKm.gif

To describe what I'm trying to achieve, when the anchor link is hover state, the background color starts to appear at its back like a progress bar to fill the width of the text **smoothly** (the gif that i generated was quite low quality that's why its not smooth).

I saw this effect in [www.webdesignerdepot.com](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/) and i'm trying to recreate it but no idea how to do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/eqqcu2cv/

```
<A href="#">
   Hello World! 
</a>

a {font-size:60px; font-weight: bolder; color:#121212; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {background:orange;}
```

Comment: Did you try to inspect the element which styles you want to copy?

Comment: did you see the gif? Yes i did. it says, background-position: -99.99% 0;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
a{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #121212;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, orange 50%);
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  background-size: 200.22% auto;
}

a:hover{
  background-position: -99.99% 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, orange 50%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  Hello World! 
</a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqqcu2cv/6/)